# Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent - ELMAH

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I have been receiving this error through ELMAH. Even though the program completes it's intended actions, I still receive this error through ELMAH and I'd like to know why and to fix it. I've gone through other threads and tried to use those suggestions but nothing I've read so far doesn't seem to work.

It's intended action is to create an excel document and then redirect the user to the page they were just on.

ActionResult:

```
 public ActionResult ExportClaimNumberReport(int ClientID, string ClaimNo) {
    ClaimNumberViewModel model = ClaimNumberReport(ClientID, ClaimNo);

    CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(
        model.ReportData.ToList(), 
        model.ReportDescription + (".xlsx"), 
        HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Response);
    ViewBag.client = client;

    Response.Buffer = true;

    Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
    if (!Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected) {
       Response.Redirect("/Error/ErrorHandler");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("ErrorHandler", "Error");
}
```

If you need anymore info, just let me know

Answer (score 3):

You will get the error because you are doing 2 redirects.

Once here

```
Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
```

And then again here:

```
return RedirectToAction("ErrorHandler", "Error");
```

So the first redirect will write a redirect header to the response stream, then the second would try to do it again, but obviously you can't send http headers to the browser twice so it throws an exception. However the user won't notice because by the time the exception is thrown the browser has already been told to redirect elsewhere.

What you want to do is just call the Redirect method as the return statement from your controller action.

So replace all this:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
if (!Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected) // this would always be false anyway 
{
   Response.Redirect("/Error/ErrorHandler");
}
return RedirectToAction("ErrorHandler", "Error");
```

With this:

```
return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString())
```

Although why you are redirecting the browser back to the referring page is unclear.

Comment: Hi, the original code I had was the code you had suggested. I realise the code I had was rather strange but I had it because I was trying some solutions which were posted online. However, I realised that I didnt even need to return anything so I made the ActionResult into a void